# How to center one item with flexbox in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have the following component in React Native:

```
  <View styleName="nav">
    <Back />
    <Image styleName="logo" style={{ alignItems: "center", alignSelf: "center", justifyContent: "center" }} source={Img} />
  </View>
```

As you can see, I am trying just about everything to center the logo, with no luck. Every example I am seeing for flexbox shows > 2 items.

Nav has the following styles:

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70;
  padding-top: 20;
}
```

Logo size is set:

```
.logo {
  width: 100;
  height: 40;
}
```

Right now I am getting something like this:

```
[<Back                           Logo]
```

I want something like this:

```
[<Back            Logo               ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `<Back/>` component's `flex-basis: 50%;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe silly one, but try to wrap logo into the container and set `width` of that container and `width` of `<Back />` to 33% like this:

```
  <View styleName="nav">
   <Back styleName="back" />
   <View styleName="logoContainer">
     <Image styleName="logo" style={{ alignItems: "center", alignSelf: "center", justifyContent: "center" }} source={Img} />
   </View>
  </View>
```

And in styles:

```
.logoContainer {
  width: 33%;
  height: 40;
}

.back {
  width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>

<View style={{flex: 2}}>   // it may vary according to you want

 <Back /> // your Back component

</View>

<View style={{flex: 8, alignItems: 'center'}}> // you can also adjust flex 

 <Image styleName="logo" source={Img} /> // give height width to image

</view>

</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row',  alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>

<View style={{position:'absolute',left:10}}>   // it may vary according to you want

 <Back /> // your Back component

</View>

<View style={{}}> 

 <Image styleName="logo" source={Img} /> // give height width to image

</view>

</View>
```